# How can I return the audio response from polly from within a lambda function?

Tags: c#, python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-polly

So this question might seems foolish at first, but I want to do a few different things on the server/lambda side of the equation and this is the end of my pipeline. I'd like to call this lambda function from c#, do some things with the text, then finally call the polly function and return the audio. However when I run the end of my pipeline code (below) I get:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f569f14abe0> is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
      238,
      "dumps",
      "**kw).encode(obj)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      199,
      "encode",
      "chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      257,
      "iterencode",
      "return _iterencode(o, 0)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
      110,
      "decimal_serializer",
      "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Why can't I just return what polly returned to the lambda function straight back to the user?

**lambda code:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('polly')
    response = client.synthesize_speech(
        OutputFormat='mp3',
        Text="Hello world, let's dance!",
        TextType='text',
        VoiceId='Salli'
    )
    return response
```

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know python, but the interface between the world and all Lambda functions (regardless of language) is a JSON interface.  JSON is a character-based object serialization format and cannot transport raw binary data, hence a `TypeError` with content that `is not JSON serializable`.  Encoding the the raw audio data as base64 -- which is binary on the input and character on the output when encoding, the reverse when decoding -- then decoding it back to binary data on the receive side -- is the piece you are missing... though I have no idea how that is done in python.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I'll give it a go, if I figure it out from that the answer is yours.